# how to send image through api and store it in models in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, json, api, paperclip

I use paperclip for storing images in s3 and now i need to get the image through api and store it in the models as i do with the form. The db contains

- pic_file_name
- pic_content_type
- pic_file_size
- pic_updated_at

These are the fields present but how to send the image as json and fill the values for that fields. Please help me doing this.

Answer (score 0):

i'll give u the example from my task

**Controller**

def create

```
@locationid = InformationSchema.count_by_sql("SELECT AUTO_INCREMENT FROM `information_schema`.`tables`
                                            WHERE (table_name = 'Location') LIMIT 1") 
  @location = Location.new
  @location.longitude = params[:longitude]
  @location.latitude = params[:latitude]
  @location.placemark = params[:address]
  @location.location_description = params[:locationDescription]
  @location.date = params[:dateTime]
  if params[:file]
    @location.file = params[:file]
    @location.photo_path = "/system/images/original/" +@locationid.to_s+".jpg?t=#{Time.now.to_i}"
  end
  @location.save

render json: {:result => @location}
```

end

**Model**

First , u have to create a new model named information_schema.rb and type this

**class InformationSchema < ActiveRecord::Base**
  self.table_name = 'information_schema.tables'
**end**

And in my location.rb Model

class Location < ActiveRecord::Base

attr_accessible :date, :id, :latitude, :location_description, :longtitude, :photo_path, :placemark , :file
  attr_accessor :file_file_name, :file_content_type
  has_attached_file :file, :styles =>{:medium => "300x300", :small => "100x100"},
                    :path => ":rails_root/public/system/images/:style/:id.jpg",
                    :default_url => "/system/images/:style/:id.jpg"
end